# Mediapipe time delay

Tags: python, time, mediapipe

I"m currently using mediapipe to implement a pose detection algorithm.
I've implemented multiple poses and put them in an array so i can iterat thorugh them in a pose sequence
however Im trying to implement it so that I have to do certain poses within a certain range of time eg
I do pose 1 and in 3 second I must do the next pose

I've so far tried time.sleep() which wont work since it'll pause the actual program to sleep and pause the video input stream

I've found a python forum that uses the following

```
import time
start = time.time ()
while time.time () < start + 4 :
    pass
```

which i've tried and also doesn't seem to work
I also would like to ideally print out the time count down so i know how much time i've got left to do the next pose

any suggestions ?

this is what i've done so far

```
gesturearray = [TPose_Cal(tpose_left, tpose_right),  downPose(downleft, downright)]

        # for i in range(0, len(gesturearray), +1):
        gesture = gesturearray[gesturePosInArray]
        if gesture == "T-Pose":
            print("T-Pose Initiated")
            while time.time() < start + 4:
                pass
            gesturePosInArray += 1
            gesture = gesturearray[gesturePosInArray]
            if gesture == "Down Look":
                gesturePosInArray += 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried using a loop to easily iterate through the list however that'll pause mediapipe itself which is not what I'd want